# Why does "ping foo.local" resolve but "dig foo.local" does not?

Tags: network, dns, ping

**Mostly this is educational for me at this point.  I don't have any practical problems.**

I have a somewhat inflexible cable modem with most features turned off because of random restrictions it seems on how you can configure the features.  This includes the DHCP server.  I have a pi-hole configured to be the DHCP server (and DNS).  Its address is fixed at 192.168.1.2.  The gateway is 192.168.1.1

`/etc/resolv.conf` has

```
search local
nameserver fe80::ca9e:43ff:fe6f:b23a
nameserver 192.168.1.2
```

The bottom of `scutil --dns` has

```
DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : local
  nameserver[0] : fe80::ca9e:43ff:fe6f:b23a%14d
  nameserver[1] : 192.168.1.2
  if_index : 14 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)
```

A ping of one host in particular resolves and pings the host.  A `dig foo.local` does not resolve.  I can add the `@192.168.1.2` and it does not resolve either.

`ip addr` on the pi-hole gives

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:06:39:a5:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2603:8081:502:aa7b::5d/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 600018sec preferred_lft 600018sec
    inet6 2603:8081:502:aa7b:f881:22f0:6895:7c8e/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 298sec preferred_lft 298sec
    inet6 fe80::c721:7dd3:4e22:67b1/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip link show` has

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:06:39:a5:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Update 1:

`arp -a` has this entry:

```
cax30 (192.168.1.1) at c8:9e:43:6f:b2:3a on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

so the IPv6 address is my router.

Update 2:

My main question at this point is about `dig`.  Why is it not returning a resolved address?  Perhaps I need to add arguments or options, etc.

Comment: The title seems to ask a different question then the post itself (which doesn't seem to ask any question), can you please be more specific about what your actual question is (and remove things which aren't related to it)?

Comment: @nohillside I'm happy to flex but the title is the question.  All of the other info in the post are answers to questions that other folks are likely to ask me.

Comment: If `ping foo.local` works, why bother about `dig foo.local`? You already established that `foo.local` gets successfully resolved so DNS seems to work. Also, on second read, your post actually asks several questions (what is %14d, where does my IPv6 address come from, something about resolv.conf and maybe more). So which specific problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @nohillside How about the post now?

Comment: Does dig exist on that modem? Or did you turn it off when you played with settings?

Comment: @SolarMike I know only how to use the GUI (web interface) on the modem.  It is a Netgear CAX30

Comment: The .local domain is a pseudo-top-level domain handled by Bonjour, so `dig` won't work. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457525/11417

Comment: @nohillside I need to study that and fully understand it.  I've used .local for so long (I'm an Apple nerd) that I thought it was normal.  Thank you.